# SQL Bulk Insert - Access is denied (Error Code 5)

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, windows-server-2012

Ok, one physical server running Hyper-V. One VM is for the SQL 2016 DB. Another VM is for the web based application that talks to the DB. A third VM that is used as the file server. All files are stored on the file server.

The file location that needs to be bulk inserted is shared with the DB Service Accounts (currently set to specifically made domain accounts - one for each service).

The file can't be imported - access is denied. I've tried setting the share to Everyone - still doesn't work. I even changed the Security Policy to allow Anonymous users the same permissions as Everyone - still doesn't work.

I don't know how to go about this Delegation method so not sure what to do there.

What else can I do to get a simple file to import into a DB?

Comment: How are you attempting to import the files?

Comment: Bulk Insert, with the file path as \\ServerName\ShareName\Folder\File etc

Comment: You set the share's permissions to allow the service accounts, but did you also set the NTFS permissions on the folders themselves? If you select a folder within the share, and look at the permissions, does the service account have permission to read?

Comment: As far as I can see, it has all permissions needed. Nothing is missing.

Comment: In that case I would verify that the AD configuration for these domain accounts allows them to access network resources.

Comment: Shouldn't they be able to by default? All other accounts have been able as, as every single file in on a share. Also, running the bulk insert on the DB machine, rather than from the App machine, works fine. It only fails when doing this double hop business.

Comment: Where is the access denied error coming from, Windows or SQL? Can you post the error message and your script if you're using one? Have you set the SQL Server instance to allow remote login and use TCP/IP?

Comment: Error comes from SQL. Remote Login is allowed and it uses TCP/IP. I use SSMS on the App VM, rather than the DB VM itself. Error message is simply "Cannot bulk load because the file (file name) could not be opened. Operating system error code 5 (access is denied).

Comment: I've turned on the audit trail on the folder, and when the DB connects to find the file, it logs on as 'Anonymous' rather than the actual account it should use. I've been spending hours this evening trying to get delegation to work (by reading this website https://thesqldude.com/2011/12/30/how-to-sql-server-bulk-insert-with-constrained-delegation-access-is-denied/ ) but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled kerberos? If the connection is coming in as Anonymous, dosent it mean that the connection is using NTLM and its a double hop issue?

Comment: As far as I can see, it is enabled. The Users and the Computers are trusted for delegation.

Comment: Further from this, I ran a little query in SSMS and it is not using the SPN's. Checking the server logs, it says it fails to login as them so therefore reverts back to NTLM. I don't know where it's going wrong though. The SQL Log sayd Windows return code 0x2098 state 15.

Comment: Hope you queried sys.dm_exec_connections.  auth_scheme column should show if the connections are using kerberos.  I believe the first step would be to make sure the connections to sql server uses kerberos.

Comment: Yes, at some point yesterday, it started to partially work. Not sure what I did though. When I connect on the App's machine, it does state the connection is Kerberos - the Bulk Insert works fine. When the PHP Script connects via Apache, using the same Windows Domain Account for Windows Authentication, it doesn't work. Not sure why though as the process should be the same. At least part of the issue is resolved.